# Neo4j Timetree query

Tags: neo4j

I am new in neo4j and is there any query to get the session nodes from 2021-05-20 to 2021-05-28?

Here are my nodes

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would actually be to avoid the timetree entirely, set the relevant activityAt date property on :Session nodes, create an index on it, then use Cypher to query it leveraging the index.

```
MATCH (s:Session)
WHERE date("2021-05-20") <= s.activityAt <= date("2021-05-28")
RETURN s
```

Timetrees were much more useful before temporal properties and temporal index lookups were introduced in Neo4j 3.4.x.

Comment: thanks for that answer. I just realized the "official" "Graph Databases" book is quite old by now. It introduces TimeTrees as a way to query by time.
If I understand correctly I can create an index on a date property and that will also speed up ranged where clauses ?
Querying TimeTrees looks ridiculously verbose and I would love to skip that part :)